# ActionScript 3 addEventListener to a Sprite

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, adobe

I try to add an event handler to a sprite object but it doesn't affect anyway what is my problem?

```
...
my_sprite_object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleEvent);

addChild(my_sprite_object);
...


public function handleEvent(event:MouseEvent):void {
//do some stuff here
}
```

Sultan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set the [Sprite.buttonMode](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Sprite.html#buttonMode) to true?

If yes, can it be that something else is already capturing the click event and is not letting it bubble further?

Comment: OK now works thanks @dain and how to do the same with the shape object?

Comment: Shape is not an InteractiveObject, so you can't unfortunately. Just put your Shape inside a Sprite! PS: if the answer helped, please mark it as correct answer and / or vote up ;)